# Ubuntu 18.04 server black screen

Tags: server, 18.04, amd-graphics, nomodeset

I am try to install the 18.04 server but the screen is black. The Desktop version works well, but with the server version the screen is black. To install it i needed add to grub start "nomodeset" but after install the screen is black. I have a A10-9700E.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, after having researched to find the problem, I was putting the "*nomodeset*" option in the wrong line.